# Use of Ajax controls in SharePoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Can we use an Ajax control toolkit in SharePoint 2007?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the following blog entry, *[Using the AJAX Control Toolkit in SharePoint](http://weblogs.asp.net/jan/archive/2007/02/26/using-the-ajax-control-toolkit-in-sharepoint.aspx)*.

Comment: what assemblies we have to refer in the web.config. iam using ajaxtoolkit of v 3.5.0.0 and i am getting this error : AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.5.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' uses 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the Ajax Config feature available on Codeplex. This feature makes the necesary modifications inside the web.config so you don't have to go in and make them yourself. Didn't test it with the Ajax ToolKit, but if it works with a custom Ajax control, I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work with controls found in the toolkit.

Here's the link: http://features.codeplex.com/releases/view/2502